# How to get the valid bit length of long double in C++?

Tags: c++

Via `std::numeric_limits`, we can get some kinds of information of `long double`, such as max/min value. And the memory usage could be get by `sizeof(long double)`.

But the valid bytes/bits of `long double` is not specified in C++ standard, it may be 80/96/128 or others, So is there a compile-time method to get the valid bit length?

A portable method is better.

```
void dump(auto x)
{
    auto vss = bit_cast<bitset<sizeof(x) * 8>>(x);
    cout << vss.to_string().substr(0, 48) << ' ' << vss.to_string().substr(48) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    long double x = 0;

    dump(x);
    dump(-x);

    return 0;
}
```

On x86-64, you would see only the 79th bit has been fliped. So there are only 80 bits of all 128 bits is valid.

Comment: A `long double` could even be 64-bit, and the same as a `double`.

Comment: `sizeof(long double)` ?

Comment: What do you mean by valid bits here?

Comment: I assume that you want dont sizeof because you mentioned that, but what do you want and why?

Comment: @RichardCritten Maybe not all of the bytes are valid. On my x86-64 PC, sizeof(long double)==16, but only 10 bytes are used, and the others are effect-free for its value.

Comment: @xxhxx `but only 10 bytes are used` why do you think so?

Comment: That information is platform specific, and is not accessibly exposed by the C++ standard.  You'd have to concoct your own schema for portability, and then implement that on each platform you care about.

Comment: @gerum On x86-64 PC, although sizeof(long double)==16, but only 10 bytes are actually be used, and the sign bit is at 79's postion.

Comment: An x86-64 PC uses the [IEEE 754 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which does not waste any bits.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`?

Comment: @Dúthomhas But I have just dumped a `long double`, the sign bit is at 79's postion. And the min/max value is correspond to the bit layout of 1+15+64 .

Comment: You need to be more specific how the information in std::numeric_limits<long double> is not enough. It is far from only min and max there

Comment: If you can assume the sign bit is the most significant, can't you just use that bit position (e.g cast to int and use xor between x and -x)?

Comment: @JohnBayko It's a very good idea, and I have post it into an answer.

Comment: @xxhxx -- you're right; don't let the criticisms get you down. One common implementation for `long double` on PCs is exactly what you describe: `sizeof(long double)` is 16, but the implementation is IEEE extended double, which is 80 bits. That's because the math processor on the x86 uses 80 bits for its internal calculations.

Comment: @Dúthomhas -- IEEE 754 extended double uses 80 bits; compilers that use that as `long double` typically use 16 bytes to hold the value, "wasting" the top bits.

Comment: Ah, I see where OP is bothered. Yes, alignment and storage is always an issue.

Comment: @xxhxx Why do you need to dump anything to find bit layout? It is right there in the <cfloat> header.

Comment: @PeteBecker but <cfloat> tells us all bits which are used to construct (any) float. I put out answer how to get it all back. Are there floats where there is, say, hole between mantissa and exponent? Did c++ ever allowed such things?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux -- the C and the C++ standards say almost nothing about how floating-point types are represented. Most implementations use IEEE-754, and in C++ you can check whether that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bit>
#include <cstddef>

constinit size_t valid_bits = []
{
    long double zero{};

    struct long_double_bytes
    {
        unsigned char b[sizeof(long double)];
    };

    long_double_bytes x = std::bit_cast<long_double_bytes>(zero);
    long_double_bytes y = std::bit_cast<long_double_bytes>(-zero);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(long double); i++)
    {
        x.b[i] ^= y.b[i];
    }

    size_t r = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(long double) && !x.b[i]; i++)
    {
        r += 8;
    }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 8 && !((x.b[i] >> j) & 1); j++)
    {
        r++;
    }

    return r + 1;
}();
```

A compile-time solution.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't just counting parts bits enough?

Along the lines

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>

static unsigned int ilog2(unsigned int val) {
    if (val == 0) return UINT_MAX;
    if (val == 1) return 0;
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    while (val > 1) {
        val >>= 1;
        ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int bitsinLDBL = LDBL_MANT_DIG; // mantissa
    bitsinLDBL += ilog2(LDBL_MAX_EXP);       // exponent
    bitsinLDBL += 1u;                        // sign bit

    std::cout << bitsinLDBL << " " << bitsinLDBL/CHAR_BIT << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote, similar informations can also be retrieved with `numeric_limits<T>::digits` and `numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent`